# Is it possible to DM users with my account instead of bot ? Discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i wrote a script in python that uses discord.py to DM the users. But I need to create a bot in order to do that. Can I do the same thing while using my personal account. Basically send Dm's using my account instead of Bot.

Comment: Selfbots are against the [ToS](https://discord.com/terms) from Discord and no longer supported. I doubt you will get any help here.

Comment: You could help us out by deleting your question.  Community deletion requires three users to close-vote and three users to delete-vote.  That's a lot of work for a question that's not going to get answered.  The rule of the boy scouts is: “Always leave the campground cleaner than you found it.”

Comment: @RobertHarvey isn't it better if i left it here, i mean somebody could want the same thing in the future. And it would really help them save a lot of time surfing through internet like I did and found nothing on it.

Comment: The TOS is readily available.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `bot=false`

```py
bot.run(TOKEN, bot=false)
```